# Selenium - Disable javascript in headless geckodriver

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, geckodriver, headless

I'm trying to make headless selenium driver without JS, but I can't figure out what am I doing wrong. When I'm trying to do the same on virtual ubuntu and it's working properly without headless mode. But same result with headless.

Runnin debian and one of the newest geckodrivers.
Python 3+

```
import urllib
import bs4 as bs
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

# proxy_list = []

profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference('network.proxy.type', 1)
profile.set_preference('network.proxy.socks', 'localhost')
profile.set_preference('network.proxy.socks_port', 9000)
profile.DEFAULT_PREFERENCES['frozen']['javascript.enabled'] = False 
profile.set_preference("app.update.auto", False) 
profile.set_preference("app.update.enabled", False) 
profile.update_preferences()

options = Options()
options.headless = True

# chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
# chrome_options.add_argument('--proxy-server=socks5://localhost:9000')

# driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="./chromedriver" ,options=chrome_options)
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="/home/user/desktop/geckodriver" ,firefox_profile=profile, options=options)
driver.get('https://google.com/search?q=facebook')
print(driver.page_source)
```

With these settings, it just freezes.

Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused

Comment: Why do you want `['javascript.enabled'] = False`? What is your usecase?

Comment: Hey, I'm looking for parsing something from html code and its getting very messy with javascript.

I gave you google search bcs u can see the difference between pages with JS and without JS.